# EST time conversion with daylight saving time

Tags: java, date-format

**EST** time conversion with daylight saving time it is coming wrongly

```
private void timeConversion() {
    String s = "2016-08-29 1:40:00 AM";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
    Date timestamp = null;
    try {
        timestamp = df.parse(s);
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        System.out.println(df.format(timestamp));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

Comment: what is your expected output and what are you getting??

Comment: 1 hr is different bz daylight saving time is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time zone EST does not respect any daylight saving time offsets:

```
TimeZone estTz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST");
System.out.println(estTz.useDaylightTime()); // prints 'false'
```

That is the time zone EST will always have a -5:00 hour offset to UTC.

This is probably due to some locations in Canada, Mexiko and Central America (Panama) not using DST but using EST all the year.

If you want a time zone with DST offset, you should use something like US/Eastern or America/New_York, etc:

```
TimeZone usEasternTz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Eastern");
System.out.println(usEasternTz.useDaylightTime()); // prints 'true'
```